# How do I set the details column using Paypal's subscription buttons?

Tags: paypal

[image: Paypal subscriptions overview]

So far I have tried:

```
<input type=hidden name=custom value="$id">
<input type=hidden name=item_name value="$id">
<input type=hidden name=on0 value="id">
<input type=hidden name=os0 value="$id"/>
```

But still on a customer account who bought the subscription, details of the particular subscription he bought is not shown. Therefore the fear is he might cancel the wrong one.

Is there some magic variable someone can point out to me? I cannot find it in [Paypal's documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HI00JQU).

Comment: Hmm, looks like you can't according to Paypal themselves: http://twitter.com/#!/PayPal_MTS/status/182903128541245440

Answer (score 0):

You can't according to Paypal: https://twitter.com/PayPal_MTS/status/182903128541245440